# Null value in non-Nullable column

Tags: sql, oracle, talend

Good day,

I'm trying to migrate some datas from a table to another table with tOracleInput and tOracleOutput.
My problem is that my column is nullable, so I have blank fields.

I've checked my schema, I synchronised the columns between the tOracleInput and the tLogRow, and it seems that my column is nullable
[image]

But when I launch my job, I've got an error :

```
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Null value in non-Nullable column
    at shipdata.stk_mdm_arrival_0_1.stk_mdm_arrival.tOracleInput_1Process(stk_mdm_arrival.java:3528)
    at shipdata.stk_mdm_arrival_0_1.stk_mdm_arrival.runJobInTOS(stk_mdm_arrival.java:5474)
    at shipdata.stk_mdm_arrival_0_1.stk_mdm_arrival.main(stk_mdm_arrival.java:5331)
```

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Can you share your full schema rather than just the first column?

Comment: Also check whether the schema columns and the source query columns  are in same sequence in tOracleInput?